# How to solve the Tower of Hanoi with L pegs, a maximal height H, and the goal is to discover the largest disc.

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

I've stumbled upon an interesting variation of the Tower of Hanoi problem.

Here are the conditions :

- You have $P$ pegs ;
- On each peg can stack a maximum of $H$ discs ;
- Discs can be of various size, and not necessarily all different. The only guarantee is the existence of an unique largest disc ;
- Usual Hanoi rules apply meaning that at any time on any peg all disks are in decreasing size order (disks of same size can stack on top of each other) from the bottom to the top.

Starting on a random configuration you have to find, if it exists, the minimal path in terms of movement leading to the largest disk being uncovered.

As it is quite unusual, I thought it could make a good question (as I struggle to find an algorithm myself).

Comment: Presumably the usual Hanoi rules apply, i.e. you cannot stack a larger disc on top of a smaller disc. Are the discs all of different size? If not, are you allowed to stack two equal sized discs on top of each other? Note that even for 5 or more pegs without a maximal height limitation the optimal Hanoi solution is not known, though it is thought that the [Frame-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm) might be.

Comment: Yes disks can be of equal size as long as it is not the maximal one. You can stack disks of same sizes on top of each other and the usual Hanoi rules apply too. I think adding the height limit might make the optimal solution solvable although I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

*(this is **not** a complete solution, but rather merely some interesting facts)*

First of all, let's get some obvious information out of the way. If you have $d$ disks, $p$ pegs, and a maximum height of $h$. We know that $h\geq d$, as otherwise the starting orientation could not be set up. Also, is $p\geq d$, then the problem is easily solved by placing one disk on each peg, allowing for a solve using $d-1$ moves.

Now some slightly more complicated things. Concerning the disks of the same size, it is optimal to treat them as if they were a single disk. To prove this, imagine two identical disks $D$ are on two separate pegs. They would either be on the bottom of the stack or above another dikc of a larger size, $D_1$. This is most definitely sub-optimal, as any disk where $D\le x\le D_1$ is unable to be placed due to our bad movements. So treating any disks of the same size as one is the best option. Using this, we can refine our earlier statement to say that if the number of disk *sizes* is $S$, then if $p\geq S$ we can solve in $d-1$ moves. *(As the question states that the largest disk is unique, we can remove that possibility)*

One last piece of information that might be useful when trying to fully optimize this problem is the following: We can make many smaller towers of Hanoi to save on the pegs we use. For example, if $S=4$ and $p=3$, we can move the smallest two disks to the second and third pegs, then stack them to make room for the third disk, which after moving would reveal the largest disk and solve our problem.

Comment: $h$ is not necessarily greater or equal than $d$ since we start on a random configuration, for example, using "the next largest disc is on" notation, with $p=3 , h=5$  you could have AABCAA which is valid. As for the treatment of same sizes disc how would you handle the case were the two last disk over the largest one are of same size and you are only left with one spot for each on two other pegs ? I don't think you could treat them as one single disk considering the height limitation.

Comment: Fair points. I had not realized the random aspect of the problem. A random configuration causes any methods of solving to become increasingly more difficult, as the starting position could result in an already solved state, or cause the puzzle to be unsolvable. There would be a lengthy proof merely to decide whether a given state was solvable or not. Hence,

Comment: Hence..? I'm still waiting for your conclusion. I don't think the solvability is a huge issue, as we can, if an optimal solution is found, apply it and verify the conditions at each step, it should sort itself naturally.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't even notice that I neglected to finish the sentence. I meant that, due to the increasing difficulty of the problem due to the randomness, creating a method to find the optimal solution becomes next to impossible. As my answer states, I only have enough information to begin an attempt to assist in whoever wants to continue trying to solve the problem. Good luck on it, though. : )